# Running a SPV wallet on Arduino/ESP32?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, cpp-ethereum, light-clients, hardware-wallets

I want my ESP32 to make transactions and check for the details of blockchain using a secure method. Actually, I want to use make calls to the blockchain instead of relying on a single node. In my opinion, using an SPV wallet would be the best idea but how can I make calls to the Ethereum blockchain instead of depending solely on a single node. Is there any other secure way to make transactions to the blockchain? Need help!!!